# cout an array of something separated into columns and rows using \t?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out a way to print out a list of memory addresses stored in a file, where there will be 4 or so columns. So it'd print out 4 addresses, each one separated by a `'\t'`, and then do a new line.

I wrote this and it works, except the problem is that once the addresses become 8 long, the tab just gets even wider so it looks bad.

```
    cout << hex;
    for (int i = 0; i < getSizeA(); i++) {
        fread(&buffer, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, in);
        if (i % 4) {
            cout << "\t";
        }
        else {
            cout << "\n";
        }
        cout << buffer;
    }
    cout << endl << dec;
```

It looks like this when it's 7 or less

[image]

and then the tabs get wider after they're 8 long:

[image]

I could probably just add another `if` statement for that, but it'd probably make my code even more ugly.

Is there a better way to do this than what I'm doing? Namely, a way to separate them using `'\t'`?

Comment: [You will have better control with `std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw)

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot about io manipulators.